# Server sending Set-Cookie with different value on every request

Tags: cookies, zope

Our Zope server is sending a different value for the same cookie every time I request a page.  I'm not sure why it would be doing this.  Does it sound like it would be intentional or a misconfiguration issue we have?  It seems to only start doing this after someone logs in.

It looks like the Extensible User Folder add-on we are using is responsible for doing it.

Comment: I have not seen Zope sending a cookie upon each request - except through some badly written third-party software hooking into the authentication or traversal for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like exUserFolder is doing this intentionally. Probably for the purpose of attempting to add more security.

Answer (score 0):

In order to figure out offending software sending cookies  I suggest to add a debugger call into the ZPublisher setCookie() method. At least a debugging message will tell you when a cookie is send. And if necessary you can investigate with pdb.set_trace() the call stack to figure out the code actually calling setCookie().